# How to get Windows username using javascript for all browsers?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Windows Username</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
alert(WinNetwork.UserName); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this code for getting username, but it is working only for IE. Is there any way I can get it in all browsers?

Comment: Simple enough, you can't !

Comment: You don't. There is no standardized way to accomplish this.

Comment: Unless you have authenticated with SSO to a server, there isn't a way to take that information in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You can't.
There is no fully compatible alternative in JavaScript, as it poses an unsafe security issue to allow client-side code to become aware of the logged in user.
Each browser enforces user detection security differently.